# How to make a Field only accept Numbers in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, uicomponent, field

I am new to Magento 2.

I am trying to make a field that can **only accept numbers** for Sort Order field  on **UI Component Form**

I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to add

```
<item name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

in your specific `field` in ui_component

Comment: Thank you if i need max_lenght and min_length.. how can i achive this

Comment: max_length of what?

Comment: first try this code it will only accept the **numbers**

Comment: i have done that and its working perfectly.. thank you

Comment: i want to limit user to user numebrs between 10 and -10

Comment: Then press the tick mark on my answer to help other people as well

Comment: @WaqarAli how you handled min and max length

Comment: @mobz have you tried this?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/270786/78648

Comment: @WaqarAli yes I tried this. but this did not handle my case.

Comment: @WaqarAli my input can accept numbers like this 000342488

Comment: @WaqarAli did you get my point.
here is Mobeen Sarwar

Comment: I need this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_minlength.asp
not this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Comment: I think you can write a custom validation rule https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/add-custom-validation-rule-in-magento-2/

Comment: @WaqarAli yes i handle it with custom val

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add this one, if you want to validate user input if it is  within the range of -10 to 10.

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="validate-digits-range" xsi:type="string">-10-10</item>
</item>
```

Note: use `validate digits` instead of `validate number` when you are validating integers otherwise use number when you are validating number input with decimals.